# Cannot install PyExfil, zlib and ftplib not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, zlib, ftplib

Tryed with pip:

`pip3 install pyexfil`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyexfil in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PyExfil-1.3-py3.7.egg (1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=1.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyexfil) (2.21.0)
Collecting impacket>=0.9.0
  Using cached impacket-0.9.21.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
Collecting slackclient
  Using cached slackclient-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Collecting progressbar
  Using cached progressbar-2.5.tar.gz (10 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zlib (from pyexfil) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for zlib (from pyexfil)
```

pip version:

```
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Tryed from github (https://github.com/ytisf/PyExfil) :

`sudo python3 setup.py install`

```
Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing PyExfil.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to PyExfil.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to PyExfil.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to PyExfil.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'PyExfil.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'PyExfil.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyexfil
copying build/lib/pyexfil/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyexfil
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyexfil/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying PyExfil.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying PyExfil.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying PyExfil.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying PyExfil.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying PyExfil.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/PyExfil-1.3-py3.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing PyExfil-1.3-py3.7.egg
Removing /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PyExfil-1.3-py3.7.egg
Copying PyExfil-1.3-py3.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
PyExfil 1.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PyExfil-1.3-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for PyExfil==1.3
Searching for ftplib
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/ftplib/
Couldn't find index page for 'ftplib' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
No local packages or working download links found for ftplib
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ftplib')
```

Im pretty sure both ftplib and zlib are Python base libraries, and I can import them without problem. Python version:`Python 3.7.6`
Im not sure what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

These are bugs in PyExfil's `setup.py`:

1. The project [lists `zlib`](https://github.com/ytisf/PyExfil/blob/347f34524ba64b9aa780e041f3a10fea3d7ccb6e/setup.py#L16) in requirements. This is a bug as `zlib` is a [module from the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html), it cannot be listed as a dependency.
2. [`classifiers` is a tuple](https://github.com/ytisf/PyExfil/blob/347f34524ba64b9aa780e041f3a10fea3d7ccb6e/setup.py#L39). It must be a list.

My advice is to [report the bugs](https://github.com/ytisf/PyExfil/issues).